# Cannot compile basic tutorial in C

Tags: c, gcc, osx-lion

I am just beginning to try to learn C and have been trying to do tutorials but they won't compile. The errors seem to suggest it is an issue with me using a 64 bit OS (lion), but I can't see how that could be the case with such a simple program.

The code: (copied directly from a 'thenewboston' tutorial)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World");
    getch();
}
```

I then entered this in terminal:

```
gcc tnb_1.c
```

And the error I got was:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_getch", referenced from:
      _main in cc2nMvOk.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The compiler I am using is the standard one installed with xcode.

I am sorry if this question has an obvious answer, but as I can't get past the first hurdle I am finding it hard to learn anything.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `getch` is not a standard C function.  I would suggest finding a different tutorial.

Comment: all getch() is going to do is make you press a key before the program exits. If you're just trying to get your first program to compile, you could leave it out and meet with reasonable success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getchar()` instead of `getch()`.  `getch()` is non-standard.

Using `getchar()` will (probably) mean you need to press enter whereas `getch()` does not, but if all you're trying to do is compile a simple program to get a start with C, that probably doesn't matter to you.

Comment: Thanks, as you said changing to getchar() fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace `getch()` with `getchar()` or `getc(stdin)`, it should work.  As Oli Charlesworth suggested, though, you might want to look at different tutorials. `getch()` is in the curses library (and some old DOS compilers), so you won't be able to build an executable without linking that.  If the tutorial didn't specify that, it's probably not very good.

Comment: You are forgetting that C will assume functions that have not been declared have a certain signature. It should spit out a warning, but it is valid C code.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that what I said was misleading, so I edited my answer.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg - notice it was the linker that choked.

Comment: I also first thought that getch() is from curses but it isn't. It's from set of console functions available on some ms-dos compilers.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it looks like I need a different tutorial!